# How to map from a string to an ES6 import

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs

For example.

We have a couple of ES6 module imports, say:

```
import Module1 from './module_1';
import Module2 from './module_2';
```

Am using [Babel](http://babeljs.io) to transpile ES6 into ES5

Have another function, which given a string, returns a reference to the imported ES6 module:

```
getModule(name) {
  switch(name) {
    case "Module 1":
      return Module1;
    case "Module 2":
      return Module2;
    default:
      return null;
  }
}
```

The naming convention is pretty straight forward and consistent
So how to remove the manual switch statement ?

Initially I thought, we can get away with using eval. something like:

```
getModule(name) {
  // removes spaces. so "Module 1" to "Module1"
  const ref = name.replace(/\s+/g, "");
  return eval(ref);
}
```

But Babel changes the variable names etc 
and has pulled the carpet from under my feet.

Just to demonstrate a non-transpiled example works with:

```
var foo = function() { console.log("called foo") }
var bar = function() { console.log("called bar") }
eval("foo")() // logs "called foo"
eval("nope") // throws ReferenceError: Can't find variable: nope
```

Is it possible to get a hash of imports in a file, called say `localImports` ?
so that we can write:

```
getModule(name) {
  // removes spaces. so "Module 1" to "Module1"
  const ref = name.replace(/\s+/g, "");
  return localImports[ref];
}
```

How to implement such a function using ES6 and Babel ?
Also as a bonus, is it possible without using `eval` ?

Comment: Can you give your use case for wanting to do this?

Comment: @torazaburo am rendering a component based on user input, using react. the input and the component name have a straight forward mapping. am using a method like `getModule` to decide which component to render. would like to take advantage of the input pattern, for expressiveness and to make sure that no typo kind of errors are there in the big-ish switch statement.

Comment: The first idea that springs to mind is to have an intermediate re-export, as in `export Module1 from '/module1'; export Module2 from './module2';`. Then import them as `import * as Modules from './reexports';`. Now you can refer to your modules as `Modules[module_name]`.

Comment: @torazaburo not bad. it is self contained in a separate file, and no need to create a hash manually. although have the same comment as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39146339/how-to-map-from-a-string-to-an-es6-import?noredirect=1#comment65645684_39147899. would like to create the mapping from the module reference (eg. Module1) and file name 'module1` automatically.

Comment: If I understand what you are trying to do, I don't think you can without access to the internals of the loader.

Comment: If the modules are specifically made for that purpose (i.e. not used somewhere else) they should register themselves. `getModule` would then be a method of the registry. Otherwise I would do the registration manually, but use the same pattern. Considering how much time you have already spent on this case, you wouldn't really gain anything with an "automatic" solution, imho.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

Import the modules.

```
import Module1 from './module_1';
import Module2 from './module_2';
```

Cache the modules in local scope with whatever name you want. In this case I use the same name: Module1, Module2.

```
setModules(){
   this.Module1 = Module1;
   this.Module2 = Module2;
}
```

Get the reference to the module using a reference made in local scope.

```
getModule(name) {
   return this[name]; //e.g. name = 'Module1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're compiling the `imports` to `require` using Babel, you could just use `require` directly and make a map:

```
const modules = {
  'Module 1': require('./module_1'),
  'Module 2': require('./module_2')
};

function getModule(name) {
  return modules[name];
}
```

Comment: `require` is not necessary to create a mapping. Moreover in the OP's case the names contain spaces.

Comment: @also would like if babel or another plugin (?) can generate this `modules` hash for me. I have called it `localImports` in my question. The hash reads cleaner than a big switch in my opinion, but my reasoning for not manually maintaining this hash or switch statement is that the key and value can be wrong due to some stupid typo. and it is hard to visually check in a big switch or hash

Comment: @zeroflagL am expecting to use the return value from `getModule` in place of an import. am using ES6 imports. but same difference with require - i guess. btw spaces can be removed with something like `name.replace(/\s+/g, "")`